# Determining outstanding balance on a loan

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, finance

A loan of $17,000$ dollars is to be repaid in annual installments of $2,100$ dollars, the first due in one year, followed by a final smaller payment. If the effective rate of interest is $8.8$ percent, what is the outstanding balance owed immediately after the $5th$ payment?

Im pretty confused on how to go about solving this, I know that outstanding balance is equal to the payment amount times the present value at a specified time, but I am confused how to go about setting up the equation properly.

Comment: I dont´know, if I understand the exercise right. It is payed back $\$2,100$ five times, is that right ? What does *"...followed by a final smaller payment."* mean in this context ?

Comment: i think it means that after the final payment (5th payment is not the final payment) a smaller payment is made (ie. >2100)

Comment: Therefore we only have to consider the five payments of 2,100 dollars each, right ?

Comment: correct id assume, but maybe you must factor in the final smaller payment to determine the number of payments needed in order to calculate outstanding balance?

Comment: no i dont, but i know 14 000 is incorrect since when i input it in webwork it comes up as incorrect. It is the last problem in this set and I'm absolutely stumped..

Comment: Sorry I meant that it is about $\$13,400$. See my calculations below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The future value of the loan after 5 years is $17,000\cdot(1.088)^5$.

The future value of the 5 payments is

$C_5=2100\cdot (1.088)^4+2100\cdot (1.088)^3+2100\cdot (1.088)^2+2100\cdot (1.088)^1+2100\cdot (1.088)^0$

- The first payment has to be compounded 4 times.
- The last payment has not be compounded.

$2100\cdot \left[ (1.088)^4+ (1.088)^3+ (1.088)^2+2100\cdot (1.088)^1+ (1.088)^0 \right]$

The expression in the brackets is the partial sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). Therefore

$C_5=17,000\cdot(1.088)^5-2100\cdot \frac{1-1.088^5}{1-1.088}$

I hope it helps.